# getting error "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, javascript-objects

I am getting below error
**"Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type"**
I don't know how to solve that error.. here is my code

```
  export interface IDropDown {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}
export enum BOOKING_TYPE {
  FC = 'FC',
  LC = 'LC',
  TUFFING = 'TUFFING',
}
  export interface IImportBookingData {
      booking_type: IDropDown | null;
  }
  let bookingData: IImportBookingData;
  const iscl = [BOOKING_TYPE.LC, BOOKING_TYPE.TUFFING].indexOf(bookingData?.booking_type?.value) !== -1;

  console.log(iscl)
```

code Link

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/ATCmA8AcHsCcBdgEsB29SwGYEMDGpgBJAEVmkmOgHcVgBvAWACgQAbbAI1FYC5gBneLFQBzANzMQAN2ysArqD6DhKccwC+zCDARgUcgLbAAQgHlTAaUIA5AOIB9ACoBNAAoBRepOAAxAMLAALzAAOT+IQA03gAyAcEhsZHejgCqPj42tkGhqemZSUyaLGBQcIio6Fh4BISEBjrwxtDQANaixNjw2F7FICAczW2q9vAAnpCKRKTklDTAAD7A+qysEsVFbKCIA63tndh8tfVlTbuqHV1rILjQKILI-Lis2QDaZpaZTm7uAHSxESZzFY7F8PD9chk7ABdH6oAAmEFMmAAFDshiILtgAPw-NGiEbjUA4mTyUAASmAAEJAsEALQARjW3hud2grFAP1Y0BEyKQj1YZOYQA

any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The type `booking_type` is defined as `IDropDown`. But, later your are accessing the `value` prop of the `booking_type` inside the `indexOf`.

Here, the `value` is `string` and it will show the type error. To overcome that, you need to type cast the value.

```
const iscl = [BOOKING_TYPE.LC, BOOKING_TYPE.TUFFING]
   .indexOf((bookingData?.booking_type?.value) as BOOKING_TYPE) !== -1;
```

Here the `as BOOKING_TYPE` will take care the type casting errors.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export enum BOOKING_TYPE {
  FC = 'enumFC',
  LC = 'LC',
  TUFFING = 'TUFFING',
}
export interface IDropDown {
  label: string;
  value: BOOKING_TYPE; // value should be of type BOOKING_TYPE
}
export interface IImportBookingData {
    booking_type: IDropDown;
}
// assing value first
let bookingData: IImportBookingData = {
  booking_type: 
  {label:"hello", value: 'LC'}
};

const iscl = [BOOKING_TYPE.LC, BOOKING_TYPE.TUFFING]
                     .indexOf(bookingData.booking_type.value) !== -1;

console.log(iscl)
```

### Also check this solution

```js
// export enum BOOKING_TYPE {
//   FC = 'enumFC',
//   LC = 'LC',
//   TUFFING = 'TUFFING',
// }

export type BOOKING_TYPE = "enumFC" | "LC" | "TUFFING";

export interface IDropDown {
  label: string;
  value: BOOKING_TYPE;
}
export interface IImportBookingData {
    booking_type: IDropDown;
}
// assing value first
let bookingData: IImportBookingData = {
  booking_type: 
  {label:"hello", value: 'LC'}
};

// const iscl = [BOOKING_TYPE.LC, BOOKING_TYPE.TUFFING]
//                     .indexOf(bookingData.booking_type.value) !== -1;
const iscl = ["LC", "TUFFING"].indexOf(bookingData.booking_type.value) !== -1;

console.log(iscl)
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).